# IBM MobileFirst 8 Java Adapter will not accept json with arrays in the body

Tags: java, json, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs

We're having an issue with a IBM MobileFirst 8 Java adapter. We have a simple method, accepting application/json. It succeeds when the json sent to the adapter is simple:

`{"id":2, "priority": 45}`

However, it "fails", when the json is "complex":

`{"id":2, "priority": 45, "list": [{"member": "a"}, {"member":"b"}]}`

The client receives a 500-error. There is no exception, nor anything in the logs to shed a light on what can cause the issue.

The adapter resource method is simple:

`@ApiOperation(value = "Post a object", notes = "")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Returns the posted object") })
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/create")
    public Response create(JSONObject object) {
        logger.info("Object retrieved"); // Never triggers if "complex" json
        logger.info(object);
        return Response.ok(object).build();
    }`

The issue is seen on both a IBM MobileFirst 8 instance running on IBM Websphere Liberty and in the IBM MobileFirst 8 DevKit.

Anyone know what could cause this, or have ideas on what to do to to find the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be to change the method signature to create(String object) and then parse it to json afterwards, like so:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Post a object", notes = "")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Returns the posted object") })
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/create")
public Response create(String object) {
    JSONObject json = JSONObject.parse(object);
    logger.info("Object retrieved"); 
    logger.info(json);
    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```